# How to call a javascript function from inside jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scope

I am trying to clean up some code and separate it into different functions. Something is not working and I think it has to do with scope. I am trying to execute `loadSubscriberList()` from inside a jQuery change event listener.

```
showUserList: function (res) {
    $('#cvUser').append('<option value="">  - Select a user - </option ');
    $.each(res.UserList, function (key, value) {
        $('#cvUser').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.firstName + " " + value.lastName + " " + value.userid + '</option>');
    });

    $('#cvUser').on('keyup change', function () {
        if ($('#cvUser').val()) {
            $('#subscriberSelectView').html('');
            var showSubscribers = $($("#subscriberSelect").text());
            $("#subscriberSelectView").append(showSubscribers);
            this.loadSubscriberList();
        } else {
            $('#subscriberSelectView').html('');
        }
    });
},

loadSubscriberList: function () {
    var postData = {
        'usr': $('#cvUser').val()
    }

    appNS.tpmBase.ajaxReq(
        '',
        postData,
        '/rsc/cvr/gsl',
        null,
        null,
        $.proxy(this.handleShowUserList, this)
    )
},
```

> Uncaught TypeError: this.loadSubscriberList is not a function

Comment: Where do you call `loadSubscriberList` from that is giving you that error? Can you post that code.

Comment: Try to place it before ShowUserList.

Comment: this.loadSubscriberList() in $('#cvUser').on('keyup change'), presumably. "this" inside a jQuery event handler refers to the element target of the event (#cvUser), so that's why it's saying it doesn't have that function.

Comment: Tip: you can cache `var cvUser = $('#cvUser')` and reuse it rather than jumping into the DOM every time. Then do `cvUser.on('event')`.

Comment: try `window.loadSubscriberList: function (){ //your code }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
$('#cvUser').on('keyup change', function () {
  if($('#cvUser').val()){
    $('#subscriberSelectView').html('');
    var showSubscribers = $($("#subscriberSelect").text());
    $("#subscriberSelectView").append( showSubscribers );
     loadSubscriberList($('#cvUser').val());
  }
  else {
    $('#subscriberSelectView').html('');
  }
});
} ,

loadSubscriberList: function(cvUserVal) {
  var postData = {
   'usr': cvUserVal
  }
```

changed `this.loadSubscriberList()` to `loadSubscriberList($('#cvUser').val());` and added `cvUserVal` as a parameter to `loadSubscriberList()` function.

Comment: I get the error, "loadSubscriberList is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the meaning of `this` is dynamic.

In the inner function, your keyup/change handler, `this` is the `#cvUser` element.

A workaround is to keep a reference to the outer `this`. By custom we use `that`.

```
showUserList: function(res) {
    var that = this;
    ...
    $('#cvUser').on('keyup change', function() {
        ...
        that.loadSubscriberList();
        ...
    });
},
```